# dataTableOutput fit column size

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

Building a Shiny Dashboard where I need to render a matrix.
For that I plan to use a `DT::renderDataTable`.

Everything is inside a FluidRow with a column size of 3 (out of 12).
The DataTable spread out of the defined column.

How can I force the table to fit the column and don't go over it ?

[image: Shiny Dashboard Fail]

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you can use `splitLayout` to obtain your desired output.  Try this

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Test App"
  ),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody(
    splitLayout(cellWidths = c("25%", "25%", "50%"),
                DTOutput("t1"), DTOutput("t2"), DTOutput("t3") 
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$t1 <- renderDT({mtcars})
  output$t2 <- renderDT({mtcars[9:15,]})
  output$t3 <- renderDT({mtcars[21:32,]})
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image: output]

Comment: I don't want a slider, I want to shrink the table to fit the space allowed by the columns